# "You know what they say..." in Japanese

Tags: words

So, I'm living in Japan right now, and I've been stocking up on idioms to make my speaking a little less stilted. In English, I like to proceed an idiom with something like "You know what they say," or "We have a saying-" but I can't find a similar structure in Japanese via googling, and of course Genki isn't very useful either.
Is there something like that in Japanese?

Comment: [maybe something like this?](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%AB%BA%E3%81%AB) and maybe [this](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%84%E3%82%8F%E3%82%86%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could say:

> (ほら、)よく言うでしょう、～～って。
>   (ほら、)よく言うだろう、～～って。 (← casual, masculine)
>   (ほら、)よく言うじゃないですか、～～って。
>   (ほら、)よく言うじゃない、～～って。(← casual, a bit feminine)
>   etc...